# Count of values across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, count

I have a dataset with a set of values dispersed over multiple columns:

| ID | Priority 1 | Priority 2 | Priority 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2308 | Writing | Reading | Reading |
| 0329 | Reading | Communication | Writing |
| 2389 | Communication | Writing | Communication |
| 2934 | Writing | Communication | Writing |

And I would like the output to be a table where the first column are the unique values found (Writing, Reading, Communication) and the rest of the columns are the priorities (Priority 1, Priority 2, Priority 3). In each column should be the count of the priority witin that instance. The output should look like:

| Priority Type | Priority 1 | Priority 2 | Priority 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Writing | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Reading | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Communication | 1 | 2 | 1 |

In my actual dataset, there are many priorities so if possible could we include 1:n for columns?

Thank you in advance.

*Edit
Table has been updated with new column for clarification. I would like to ignore the ID column completely and only have a count of the priorities in each of the priorities columns.

Comment: Better to provide data as a `dput` that can be copied easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
table(stack(df))

               ind
values          Priority 1 Priority 2 Priority 3
  Communication          1          2          1
  Reading                1          1          1
  Writing                2          1          2
```

If you want it as a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(df)))
              Priority 1 Priority 2 Priority 3
Communication          1          2          1
Reading                1          1          1
Writing                2          1          2
```

Comment: `reshape(data.frame(table(stack(df))), dir = "wide", timevar = "ind", idvar = "values")`

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to giving me what I'm looking for but it's getting sorted by the first column in my dataset that I eliminated for brevity. The 'Priority' columns are each have an 'ID' value for the first value in the dataset. Sorry for the confusion. Any suggestions? I can edit the original question if that is helpful

Comment: @kioti plese edit the question accordingly

Comment: @kioti justt remove the id column ie `table(df[-1]))`

Answer (score 2):

Try `sapply`

```
sapply( dat, table )

              Priority1 Priority2 Priority3
Communication         1         2         1
Reading               1         1         1
Writing               2         1         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `values_fn = max` argument from `pivot_wider` function of `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols= everything()
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  add_count(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from =n,
    values_fn = max
  )
```

```
  value         Priority1 Priority2 Priority3
  <chr>             <int>     <int>     <int>
1 Writing               2         1         2
2 Reading               1         1         1
3 Communication         1         2         1
```